# how to sum up the values for custom groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have select query that returns count of elements in each subgroup (as on the pic below). Now I want to do 2 things:

1. limit number of subgroups
2. sum counts for the limited subgroups

[image: SELECT results]

I want to get following results (as on the picture below): there are only 3 subgroups (subgroup 1 and 2 from the current results stay as they are and all other subgroups are grouped together as subgroup3 and their respective counts are summed up. The same for all the groups.

[image: desired_results]

```
SELECT inner_counts.level4 as group,  inner_counts.luc as subgroup, SUM(inner_counts.count_no)

FROM (SELECT original_table2.level
, CASE original_table2.level 
    WHEN 1 THEN 1
    WHEN 2 THEN 2
    WHEN 3 THEN 3
    ELSE 4
    END as level4, 

original_table1.classes 
, CASE original_table1.classes 
                            WHEN 1
                            THEN 1
                            WHEN 2
                            THEN 2
                            ELSE 3
                          END
as luc, 
count(original_table2.id) as count_no

FROM original_table2
LEFT JOIN original_table1
ON original_table1.plot_id=original_table2.id
WHERE original_table2.selected_for_field>0
AND original_table1.reachability_2=2
AND original_table1.classes IN (SELECT DISTINCT original_table1.classes
                       FROM original_table1)
AND original_table2.level IN (SELECT DISTINCT original_table2.level
                       FROM original_table2)
GROUP BY original_table2.level, original_table1.classes
ORDER BY original_table2.level ASC) as inner_counts

GROUP BY inner_counts.level4, inner_counts.luc,inner_counts.count_no
ORDER BY inner_counts.level4 ASC
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure there are more elegant methods, but this should get you the result set. Transform the value in the subgroup using a case when in a sub-query, then group.

```
create table #test
([Group] int, [SubGroup] int, [Count] int)

Insert into #test Values(1,1,175)
insert into #test values(1,2,5)
insert into #test values(1,3,29)
insert into #test values(1,4,116)
insert into #test values(1,5,5)
insert into #test values(1,6,4)
insert into #test values(1,7,8)
insert into #test values(1,8,5)
insert into #test values(1,9,479)
insert into #test values(2,1,12)
insert into #test values(2,2,33)
insert into #test values(2,3,147)
insert into #test values(2,4,6)
insert into #test values(2,5,5)
insert into #test values(2,6,38)
insert into #test values(2,7,440)
insert into #test values(2,8,67)
insert into #test values(2,9,110)
insert into #test values(3,1,256)
insert into #test values(3,2,7)
insert into #test values(3,3,17)
insert into #test values(3,4,8)
insert into #test values(3,5,428)
insert into #test values(3,6,23)
insert into #test values(3,7,26)
insert into #test values(3,8,78)
insert into #test values(3,9,1)
insert into #test values(4,1,81)
insert into #test values(4,2,425)
insert into #test values(4,3,129)
insert into #test values(4,4,327)
insert into #test values(4,5,455)
insert into #test values(4,6,126)
insert into #test values(4,7,48)
insert into #test values(4,8,287)
insert into #test values(4,9,363)
insert into #test values(5,1,239)
insert into #test values(5,2,93)
insert into #test values(5,3,373)
insert into #test values(5,4,53)
insert into #test values(5,5,109)
insert into #test values(5,6,126)
insert into #test values(5,7,419)
insert into #test values(5,8,214)
insert into #test values(5,9,342)
insert into #test values(6,1,104)
insert into #test values(6,2,437)
insert into #test values(6,3,356)
insert into #test values(6,4,337)
insert into #test values(6,5,6)
insert into #test values(6,6,388)
insert into #test values(6,7,172)
insert into #test values(5,8,280)
insert into #test values(5,9,349)
    Select 
    [Group],
    [SubGroup],
    CountNumeric = sum([Count])

From (
    Select 
        [Group],
        [SubGroup] = Case subgroup 
                            When 1
                            Then 1
                            WHen 2
                            Then 2
                            Else 3
                          End,
        [Count]
    From #test) a
Group By 
    [Group],
    [SubGroup]
Order by 1,2 asc
```

My result set is:

```
1   1   175
1   2   5
1   3   646
2   1   12
2   2   33
2   3   813
3   1   256
3   2   7
3   3   581
4   1   81
4   2   425
4   3   1735
5   1   239
5   2   93
5   3   2265
6   1   104
6   2   437
6   3   1259
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: That works fine for grouping, but I still have in the results sums for subgroups (the subgroups have new labels, but I need to sum up all values for subgroup 3 and display this subgroup only once in each of the groups). For example: 

group|subgroup|count
1|1|123
1|2|23
1|3|211
1|3|432
and I need:
group|subgroup|count
1|1|123
1|2|23
1|3|643

Comment: @krltos...I edited the answer to make a test table/query. I think it should work. Let me know.

Comment: yes this is what I'm looking for. My query though is bit more complicated than your example and maybe that causes me problems. I put the original query in my question if you can take a look on it.

Comment: Is it giving you an error or just not giving the proper results? One small issue I see on your example query is the final group by you do should not have "inner_counts.count_no" in it since that is your aggregate.

Comment: The only problem was that I missed inner_counts.count_no in group by clause. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the OVER() PARTITION BY clause.  This will allow you to calculate separate roll ups without affecting the rest of the results.